# RMS residual normalized by standard-deviation

Tags: residuals, rms

Is there a proper name for the following misfit quantification?

```
misfit=√{∑[(xi−xi')^2/(n*i^2)]}
```

where n is the number of data points xi−xi' is the ith residual, and i is the standard deviation (uncertainty) of the ith data point.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard deviation of a data point"?

Comment: Hello and welcome to CV! It seems a scaled least absolute deviation problem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations

Comment: By "standard deviation" I am referring to the uncertainty, which in my problem is estimated from histograms about each xi. For a given xi, the uncertainty is the half-width of the best-fitting Gaussian to the histogram.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and for the lead on least absolute deviations. It seems that my deviations aren't absolute: not L1 norm, but rather the L2 norm was taken. I am thinking the misfit calculation above could be called something like "RMS normalized residual".